In R while using facet_grid function, how to keep the axis variable order same, not to reaarrange according to variable use in facet_grid
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)

data(mtcars)

my_mtcars <- mtcars %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column(var = "car") %>%
  dplyr::select(car,mpg,wt, gear)

p1 <- ggplot2::ggplot(my_mtcars, ggplot2::aes(x = mpg, y = car )) + 
  ggplot2::geom_point()

p2 <- p1 + ggplot2::facet_grid(gear ~ . , scales = "free", space = "free", switch = "y")


Issue: In p2, "car" (y-axis) variable is re-arranged according to "gear" order (e.g. 3,4,5).  But in p2, I want to keep the order of "car" (y-axix) same as order in p1, which means ignoring the order of "gear". In this particular case, the "gear" order should 4, 3 and 5. As the order is Volvo 142E (gear 4), Valiant (gear 3), and Porche 914-2 (gear 5). And the rest of the car order should follow the car order in P1
I will be thankful for any suggestions.

In p2 they are subset by gear for each facet, but within each facet the order is consistent with p1 (Alphabetical). Are you expecting a y-axis tick, for example, for Valiant in each facet but only plot a value on the 3-gear facet?

Use scales = "fixed" if you want all the cars to appear in order in each facet. As is, they appear in order, but only in their respective facet.

Dear, Seth and jon Spring many thanks. I have edited my question.

It sounds like you want the facets ordered in order of their first appearance in the data. I like forcats::fct_inorder() for this, since it just needs your data sorted how you want it to appear. That makes it possible to accommodate all sorts of multi-variable, ifelse conditions, weird sorting, etc.
my_mtcars |>
  dplyr::arrange(desc(car)) |>
  transform(gear = factor(gear) |> forcats::fct_inorder()) |>
ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = car )) + 
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(gear ~ . , scales = "free", space = "free", switch = "y")


